# Find Databricks Account URL

Tags: r, databricks

I am trying to follow this tutorial to get plotly working in Databricks. It is requiring me to get the Databricks Account URL. Does anyone know where I can find this?
https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/htmlwidgets.html

[image]

Comment: This is off-topic and will be closed. Here's my *opinion*: the databricks document you linked to contains bad coding practices, is not clear in its prerequisites, and appears incomplete. I don't have an answer for your *"what is my databricks account url"*, but my first recommendation would be to reference a better tutorial/howto. This opinion is just that, and opinions are generally discouraged on SO, so perhaps this comment is a little off-topic as well. Good luck. (BTW: please don't include images of code and such, include the text itself.)

Answer (score 0):

Your account URL is where you navigate to log in.  On AWS it often looks like

```
https://dbc-5t784e5d-d9b1.cloud.databricks.com/
```

On Azure it will look like

```
https://eastus2.azuredatabricks.net/?o=5288839412345315
```